# Can I configure the same gestures on Magic Mouse as Trackup?

Tags: mouse

Is it possible to configure a Magic Mouse to have identical gestures to the trackpad?

The similarity of both a trackpad and magic mouse, but having the gestures not be the same, is very confusing. Two finger scroll? Pinch to zoom? Three finger mission control? Can I get all of these on the Magic Mouse?

Answer (score 1):

BetterTouchTool lets you configure both devices.